# Redirect to a path relative to root path using javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, path

I'm working on a project where I have a form to add a thread as following :
[image]

The share button validate and save the thread to the database :

```
$('.share-thread').click(function() {
    // Validations

    let data = {
        '_token':csrf,
        'subject': $('#subject').val(),
        'category_id': $('#category').val(),
        'content':simplemde.value(),
        'thread_type': $('#thread_type').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        url: '/thread',
        success: function(response) {
            window.location.href = "/" + response;
        }
    });
});
```

In the controller I return a path like : /general/discussions
Now what I want is how to append this path to the root path in case of local environement I want something like this:

```
127.0.0.1/general/discussions
```

And in case of production :

```
www.domain.com/general/discussions
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just return the full path from your controller using one of the URL helpers such as [url()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-url) or [route()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route).

Alternatively there is the [ziggy](https://github.com/tighten/ziggy) package by Tighten that allows you to use named routes in your JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks I forgot named routes I create a named route with parameter and reference it with route() helper and it works fine now ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can redirect relatively:

```
window.location.href = '../'; //According to the path levels
```

or

Redirect to the domain path

```
window.location.href = '/yourPath';  //Depending on the domain
```